# Charging my laptop via powerbank, it worked!

Tags: charging, laptop

First of all let my say that i'm NOT an electrician or an electrical engineer. i'm just a guy who wanted to be able to chagre my laptop via my powerbank and this is how i did it.

The power bank i have is the Aukey 30000mAh. Specs for the USB ports:
Type-C Input/Output: 5V 3A
Output (Quick Charge 3.0): 3.6V-6.5V 3A | 6.5V-9V 2A | 9V-12V 1.5A
Output (AiPower): 5V 2.4A

The power bank is able to put out 42W simultaneously, if you are charging via all the 3 ports at the same time.

The laptop needs 12V 2A to charge.

First i bought the LTC1871 DC-DC STEP-UP converter (google and you will find it)
This was the only step up converter i could find which was able to handle a 2 amp output and at the same time step up the voltage from 5v to 12v
there are a few tests of this converter on youtube but i think this is the best one:
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Y1YtPG4fFeM

Remember to set the correct output voltage on the converter before you test this setup... The converter has a lcd display that shows you in and output voltage, but it is not 100% accurate. use a voltmeter/multimeter to make sure.

Then i took two standard USB cables and cut away the end that wasn't A-Male. Cut away the wires for data (usually green and white). Twisted together the red wires (+) from each usb cable and did same thing with the black (-)
these wires are then attached to the input side of the converter. The converter is clearly marked with whats the input/output side and which is plus and minus.

I got lucky and found a power supply with the right DC-jack for my laptop. Cut the cable from the power supply and then attached it to the output side of the converter and voila! the laptop is charging :)

I haven't been able to measure the amps. 
But according to the battery indicator in windows it takes the same amount of time to fully charge the battery whether or not i use the standard power supply or my setup.

I do have some issues... 
I can't use my laptop while it's charging, the lid has to be closed or the converter shuts of. And even if the lid is closed, i still takes a few tries before converter starts and begin to charge. I have to push the on button on the powerbank a few times...
Might be fixed with som better cables, not really sure.

Comment: The answer very depends on the way all of those parts operate. My view would be this could work, looking at the numbers, but your concern about the current limit is valid, and that depends on how all (the power bank, step up converter and the 7-cable) work together.

Answer (score 1):

Laptop needs 2A * 12V = 24W. You need at least 24 W of 5V which is 4.8 A. Plus whatever the step up converter takes to work. Connecting powerbank outputs together may not work or could even break something, as those intelligent ports may need handshaking to provide power.

Comment: ok...
I have found a DC-DC step-up converter that can deliver 2amp...
Let's assume that non of the handshake/intellegens between PB and laptop work.
The PB should revert to its default setting when it comes to delivering a charge via the USB-ports. In this case  the lowest volt and amp according to the specs?
So if i could find or build a USB-y cable that has one type a and one typ c i should be able pull 5v 6A in total. Then stepping the voltage up 12 should mean i get a little under 3 Amps...? 

Thanks so much for your input guys, it's much appriciated :)